# Language not recognised in .travis.yml of project generated by CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, travis-ci

I create a CocoaPods project in Swift. But the build in Travis always fail. The error message is:

> The command "rake" exited with 1.

I found the language in Travis is recognised as Ruby instead of Swift (Objective-C). Here is the screenshot:

[image]

My .travis.yml is:

```
osx_image: xcode7.3
language: objective-c
# cache: cocoapods
# podfile: Example/Podfile
# before_install:
# - gem install cocoapods # Since Travis is not always on latest version
- pod install --project-directory=Example
script:
- set -o pipefail && xcodebuild test -enableCodeCoverage YES -workspace Example/WOWGallery.xcworkspace -scheme WOWGallery-Example -sdk iphonesimulator9.3 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty
- pod lib lint
```

Any idea what could be the reason? Thanks

Comment: Run echo "3.0" >> .swift-version add the swift version solve the issue.

Comment: Uncomment **-pod install** in .travis.yml will cause the default language becoming Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docs [Travis-ci](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/multi-os/#operating-system-differences)

> Language availability. Not all languages are available on all operating systems, and different versions maybe installed on different systems.

```
{ "os": "osx", "script": ["set -o pipefail && xcodebuild test -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s' -workspace Example/FullAuthIOSClient.xcworkspace -scheme FullAuthIOSClient-Example -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | xcpretty",
"pod lib lint --allow-warnings"], "podfile": "Example/Podfile", "language": "objective-c", "osx_image": "xcode9.4", "before_install": [
"gem install cocoapods --pre --no-rdoc --no-ri --no-document --quiet" ] }
```

**In your configuration file, the "os" value is mentioned as linux. 
Try adding your project in `mac` platform rather than linux.**

Ref: [Os Support Status](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2320)